# Как правильно передать xml soap-запрос на php

Tags: php, soap

Добрый день.

Подскажите пож. как правильно передать xml файл в soap запросом.

Вот сам xml

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v2="http://api.kartoteka.ru/auth/v2/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v2:login>
         <loginRequest>
            <login>search_api_demo</login>
            <password>search_api_demo</password>
         </loginRequest>
      </v2:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Данный запрос описан в [http://api.kartoteka.ru/docs/poiskovaya-sistema/versiya-2-0/api-soap-docs/2014-11-14-10-50-47/metod-login-v2|](http://api.kartoteka.ru/docs/poiskovaya-sistema/versiya-2-0/api-soap-docs/2014-11-14-10-50-47/metod-login-v2%7C)
Как на php отправить этот запрос на сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так:

```
$soapHeader = new SoapHeader('Пространство имен для заголовка', ['login'=>'search_api_demo', 'password'=>'search_api_demo']);
$soapClient = new SoapClient('Путь к wsdl');
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($soapHeader);
```

Логин и пароль будут передаваться автоматически при каждом запросе.

Comment: Удалось решить задачу следующим образом.
$wsdl = 'http://api.kartoteka.ru/search/v2/soap/search.wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$resultId = $client->login(array('login'=>'****','password'=>'****'));
$sessionid = $resultId->session->id;
$client->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader($wsdl,'sessionId',$sessionid));
$fullDescription = $client->searchByRequisite(array('detailSearchRequest'=>array('inn'=>'7710684990')));

Comment: Получается если меняется  $wsdl то для получения sessionId нужно вызвать повторно $client2->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader($wsdl2,'sessionId',$sessionid)); или можно использовать уже полученный sessionId ?

Comment: Если новый wsdl совместим со старым, Вам ничего менять не нужно, используйте имеющийся код. Если же не совместим, нужно смотреть новую документацию или связываться с тех поддержкой и уточнять список внесенных изменений, а на их основе модифицировать Ваш код.

Comment: Допустим если я хочу сперва получить значения из метода searchByRequest и из полученного результата вызвать метод допустим  getBoYears то для каждого wsdl мне нужно вызывать свой $client2->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader($wsdl3,'sessionId',$sessionid));
Модуль searchSoap - http://i.imgur.com/gsDlKeT.png  и модуль FinSoap - http://i.imgur.com/WPsAPQM.png.
Хотя думаю достаточно обратиться к  .../v2/soap/search.wsdl и вызвать все необходимые методы.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас уже полностью сформирован конверт SOAP - просто отправьте его на сервер запросом POST. К примеру, можно использовать для этих целей [curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, буду разбираться.
А есть какой нить пример кода чтобы можно глянуть.

Comment: Вот сам запрос. - ` $query="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:v2='http://api.kartoteka.ru/auth/v2/'>
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v2:login>
         <loginRequest>
            <login>search_api_demo</login>
            <password>search_api_demo</password>
         </loginRequest>
      </v2:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"; `

Comment: if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'http://api.kartoteka.ru/auth/v2/soap/');
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$query);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    pre($out,true);
    echo $out;
    curl_close($curl);
}

Результат вывелся http://i.imgur.com/bjU5Gr5.png, только как закинуть данное значение в переменную. Мне полученный результат необходимо передать в следующем запросе.

Comment: Результат у вас **уже** в переменной $out. Просто уберите отладочный вывод этой переменной.

Comment: Имеете ввиду передать таким образом ? <v2:sessionId>curl_exec($curl)</v2:sessionId> ?

$query_search = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:v2='http://api.kartoteka.ru/search/v2/'>
   <soapenv:Header>
      <v2:sessionId>curl_exec($curl)</v2:sessionId>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v2:searchByRequisite>
         <request>
             <detailAndSearchRequest>
               <name>ООО Картотека</name>
            </detailAndSearchRequest>
         </request>
      </v2:searchByRequisite>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";

Comment: если добавить параметр curl_setopt($authUser,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); то вывод не в браузер а возвращает  как строку.
$res = curl_exec($authUser);

Comment: Остался еще один вопрос, как отправить несколько запросов.
Вот сам код - http://i.imgur.com/iIAbeTJ.png
Вот результат - http://i.imgur.com/Ja2gYuA.png